# Why is $L(V,L(V,W))\cong L^2(V,W) $?

Tags: linear-algebra

I don't see why both spaces $L(V,L(V,W))$ and $L^2(V,W)$ have the same dimension when I try to write it with the notation with dimensions:
$$ \dim(L(V,L(V,W)))=\dim(V)\cdot \dim(L(V,W))\\=\dim(V)\cdot \dim(V)\cdot \dim(W)=\dim(V)^2\cdot \dim(W) $$
and

$$ \dim(L^2(V,W))=\dim(L(V,W)\times L(V,W)) = ?$$

Remark:
$ L(V,W):=\{f:V\rightarrow W \mid \text{f is linear}\}.$

Comment: May I ask what the definition of $L^2(V,W)$ is?

Comment: I think this expression is meant by $ L^2(V,W)=L(V,W)\times L(V,W) $ but I'm not sure.

Comment: Then the statement would be false. Perhaps $L^2(V,W)$ are supposed to be the bilinear maps from $V\times V$ to $W$?

Comment: A right! Thanks. Now I remember myself. So then I would have $$ dim(L(V,L(V,W)))=dim(V)\cdot dim(L(V,W))\\=dim(V)\cdot dim(V)\cdot dim(W)=dim(V)^2\cdot dim(W)\\=dim(V\times V)\cdot dim(W)=dim(L(V\times V,W))\\=dim(L^2(V,W)). $$

Comment: @hallo97 Are your spaces finite-dimensional?

Comment: @hallo97 careful: $\dim (V \times V) = \dim V + \dim V.$

Comment: Yes they are. I forgot to mention it because I was so focused on this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Algebraic context**
Assume that $U$, $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces over some field $k$. Then the space $\mathrm{Bilin}(U, V; W),$ consisting of *bilinear* maps $U\times V\to V$ is "the same" as $\mathrm{Hom}(U\otimes V, W)$.

Then the claim follows from [tensor-hom adjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor-hom_adjunction):
$$\mathrm{Hom}(U\otimes V, W)\simeq \mathrm{Hom}(U,  \mathrm{Hom}(V, W)),$$
which has numerous proofs. (Available in any book on commutative algebra).

However, if $U$, $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional, then it is also easy to calculate the dimensions of both sides:
$$
\begin{align*}
\dim \mathrm{Hom}(U\otimes V, W) &= \dim (U\otimes V)^*\cdot \dim W \\& = \dim U\cdot \dim V \cdot \dim W\\
&\text{ and }\\ 
\dim \mathrm{Hom}(U, \mathrm{Hom}(V, W)) &= \dim U^* \cdot \dim \mathrm{Hom}(V, W) = \dim U^*\cdot \dim V^*\cdot \dim W \\
&= \dim U\cdot \dim V\cdot \dim W 
\end{align*}
$$

---

**Analytic context** Assume that $U$, $V$ and $W$ are [Banach spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_space). Then $L(U, V)$ is the space of *bounded* linear maps and $L(U, V; W)$ is the space of *bounded bilinear* maps $U\times V\to W$.

Then there exists an *isometric* isomorphism
$$ L\big(U, L(V, W)\big) \simeq L(U, V; W).$$

The proof is not hard and can be found e.g. in K. Maurin's  *Analysis* (Part I, Theorem VII.7.3).